# How can I validate all the code enclosed between the <% and %> brackets of aspx files at build time?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, build-process

I'm starting to use Asp.net MVC. It is recommended to use the `<%` and `%>` tags to embed the source code in the HTML, since it's easier to read.

Unfortunately though Visual Studio can't detect any errors in the code at compile time. This is a very bad thing.

For example:

```
<body>
    <form action="LogOn.aspx">
        <div>
            <div><label for="txtLogOn_UserName"><%= LogOnView.UserName %> :</label></div>
            <div><%= Html.TextBox("txtLogOn_UserName")%></div>            
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

How can I be sure that `LogOnView.UserName` is a valid statement? As an analogy that code is similar to JS code; you can't know if there will be errors until you run it.

A possible solution could be to create a test project, but I don't like that idea and I don't think I should be forced to create a test project to solve this problem.

<sup>Note: This problem will not occur if I use the code-behind coding style.</sup>

Comment: I don't ensure that ASP.NET Compilation Tool can help me for solving this question.

Comment: C# code in an ASPX file is not equal to JS in a JS file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the aspnet_compiler as a post-build action:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_compiler -v / -p "$(ProjectDir)\"
```

More info [here](http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2008/05/compiling-aspx-templates-using.html).

**Edit for .NET 4.0 users:**

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_compiler -v / -p "$(ProjectDir)\"
```